Integration-by-parts with vectors
We have the integration-by-parts formula:
\begin{equation*}
\int_V \phi \,\nabla\cdot \mathbf{A}\,dV=\int_S \phi \,\mathbf{A}\,\cdot d\mathbf{S} - \int_V\nabla\phi\cdot\mathbf{A}\,dV
\end{equation*}
where $\phi$ is a scalar field and $\mathbf{A}$ is a vector field. The divergence theorem inspires this formula and helps to integrate in case we don't know, or want to compute, the divergence of $\mathbf{A}$.
We have many other integration-by-parts rules to help us with such integrations. I want to know if we have any rules for integrations of the kind:
\begin{equation*}
\int_V \mathbf{B} \,\nabla\cdot \mathbf{A}\,dV
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{A}$ are 3D vector fields.
Actually, I have an MRI reconstruction problem and in my case, I have to find:
\begin{equation*}
\int_V \nabla G(\mathbf{r',r}) \,\nabla\cdot \mathbf{H}\,dV'
\end{equation*}
where $G(\mathbf{r',r})$ is the Green's function and $\mathbf{H}$ is the magnetic field. But I want to avoid the divergence (or any kind of derivative) of $\mathbf{H}$.
I have tried writing my integration in the form:
\begin{equation*}
\int_V \frac{\partial G(\mathbf{r',r})}{\partial x_i}\mathbf{e}_i \,\nabla\cdot \mathbf{H}\,dV', \hspace{.5cm}i=1,2,3
\end{equation*}
but I am still unsure if I can use the original integration-by-parts rule since $\mathbf{e}_i$ is a vector.
Thank you very much for your help!

The trick here is that, even though the $\mathbf{e}_{i}$’s are vectors, if you are at least in Cartesian coordinates, they are constant vectors which don’t depend on the integration variables, so you can then “pull” them outside the integration, and then get an integral completely compliant with the integration by parts formula you want.
